# people detection error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all

Regarding people detection(ppl_detection), I have an error. When I run the code below

$ rosrun ppl_detection kinect_detect

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named kinect_detect below home/jkim/ros_workspace/ppl_detection

I followed the procedure introduced in the website. I modified launch/kinect.launch, then
typed

$ roslaunch ppl_detection kinect.launch

I seemed to work showing rviz screen, but when I put this command

$ rosrun ppl_detection kinect_detect

error occurs. please help.
Thank you

Jong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33652/people-detection-error/) by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/10345/problems-running-ppl_detection-in-astar-ros-pkg) can help you find the answer to your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on 2012-05-10**:
I tried that but It does'n work. It shows an error massage like "[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named kinect_detect below home/jkim/ros_workspace/ppl_detection" when I command "rosrun ppl_detection kinect_detect" What should I do ?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-05-10**:
did you did a rosmake ppl_detection to compile the code you downloaded?